Unable to Assume IAM Role in AWS Amplify Deployment
I'm encountering an issue where my AWS Amplify app is unable to assume the specified IAM role during deployment. It has worked fine before and my app works locally.
The error message I receive is:
Unable to assume specified IAM Role. Please ensure the selected IAM Role has sufficient permissions and the Trust Relationship is configured correctly.
What I have already done:
Trust Relationship:
I’ve updated the IAM role’s trust policy to allow the amplify.amazonaws.com service to assume the role, like this:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "amplify.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]

}
Permissions:
I’ve ensured that the IAM role has AdministratorAccess-Amplify and other necessary policies attached, including AWSAmplifyBackendAccessPolicy, AmazonS3FullAccess, and AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole.
Reassigned the Role:
I’ve reassigned the role in the AWS Amplify Console to ensure that it’s the correct one, and also tried reassigning it to a new role, but the issue persists.
Cleared Amplify Cache:
I’ve cleared the local environment using rm -rf amplify/ and pulled and pushed the changes with amplify pull --restore and amplify push, but the error continues.
Region Check:
Both the IAM role and the Amplify app are in the same region, so I don’t believe this is a region mismatch issue.
What I’ve tried:

Double-checked the trust relationship and permissions multiple times.
Recreated the IAM role and reassigned it in the Amplify settings.
Tried redeploying the app using the Amplify Console and CLI, but still getting the same
error.

What I need help with:
Any insights into what might be causing this issue?
Suggestions for what permissions or configurations I may have missed?
How to resolve this "Unable to assume IAM Role" error with AWS Amplify deployment?
Thanks in advance for your help!
